# ENVI FLAASH Error

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, landsat-8, atmospheric-correction, flaash

I try to run FLAASH on a Landsat 8 image.
I radiometrically corrected the image using FLAASH output parameters using ENVI 5.4.
It gives me the error message:

```
ACC error: modrd5:reading archive file header IDL error: READU: End of file encountered. Unit: 102, File: [file path]\acc.modroot.fla 
ACC_MODRD5 <( 9)>
ACC_HYPER2 <(550)>
ACC_ACC <(191)>
ENVI_ACC_EVENT <(3193)>
ENVI_FLAASH_PROCESS_MANAGER <(611)>
IDLRTMAIN <(172)>
$MAIN$ <( 0)>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error. In my case, it appears that I made a mistake on the "Ground Elevation (km)" parameter on the "FLAASH Atmospheric Correction Model Input Parameters" dialog box which must be in kilometres and not metres.